# DNN Manage Button Hides behind other UI elements

Tags: dotnetnuke

[image: DNN Manage Button Hides]

Hello,

Can anybody guide me regarding this issue. I have tried searching a lot on this issue but couldn't get the right solution for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is by design, if you mouse off the manage button it should go away.

You could also upgrade to DNN 7 where the Manage button is gone altogether.

Comment: Yeah. I got errors while installing my DNN 6 skin in DNN 7. Error : This is a legacy skin

Comment: You'll definitely want to look at fixing any errors on upgrade, but do you understand what I mean about the Manage button hiding the Elements is by design? Is it not going away after you move the mouse elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too in DNN 6.2.  If you are developing the module, you can do this:

I include in my View.ascx file:

```
<% if(DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.IsEditMode()) { %>  
   <div runat="server" id="showIfEditMode" > 
      <br /> <br /> <br />
   </div> 
<% } %>
```

This will push the module down while in Edit mode (when you will see the Manage button).

Comment: Thanks. I have switched to the latest version of DNN 7.x and everything is working great. So the <br/> tags will push the modules down.